# How do I prove this trigonometric inequality?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, convex-analysis, fractions, karamata-inequality

If $A,B,C \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. Then prove that $$\frac{\sin(A+B+C)}{\sin(A)+\sin(B)+\sin(C)} < 1$$

Comment: How about using Jensen's Inequality?

Comment: @ShreyAryan Is $\sin$ convex on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$?

Comment: No it isin't...But we can reverse the direction of the inequality.

Answer (score 2):

If $A+B+C\geq\pi$ our inequality is obviously true.

Let $A+B+C<\pi$ and $A\geq B\geq C$.

Since $(A+B+C,0,0)\succ(A,B,C)$ and $\sin$ is a concave function on $[0,\pi]$,

by Karamata we obtain:
$$\sin(A+B+C)+\sin0+\sin0\leq\sin{A}+\sin{B}+\sin{C}$$
and we are done!

Answer (score 1):

Expand using the sum formula for sine:
\begin{align}
\sin(A+B+C)&=\sin(A+B)\cos(C)+\sin(C)\cos(A+B) \\
&=\sin(A)\cos(B)\cos(C)+\sin(B)\cos(A)\cos(C)+\sin(C)\cos(A+B) 
\end{align}
Now since $A,B,C\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, we know $\max\{\cos(A),\cos(B),\cos(C),\cos(A+B)\}<1$, and therefore
$$\sin(A)\cos(B)\cos(C)+\sin(B)\cos(A)\cos(C)+\sin(C)\cos(A+B)<\sin(A)+\sin(B)+\sin(C).$$
Combining what we have so far, we see that $\sin(A+B+C)<\sin(A)+\sin(B)+\sin(C)$, and since the left hand side cannot be zero, we can divide by it to obtain the result.

Comment: But product of cosBcosC can exceed value 1, can't it?

Comment: @TaylorTed No. Their sum can, but not their product.

Comment: @TaylorTed No problem.